# Are C++ vectors in a user-defined aggregate function a POD for Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions, postgresql-12

The official postgres documentation ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/xfunc-c.html#EXTEND-CPP)) states in section "37.10.11. Using C++ for Extensibility" that

- If calling backend functions from C++ code, be sure that the C++ call stack contains only plain old data structures (POD). This is necessary because backend errors generate a distant longjmp() that does not properly unroll a C++ call stack with non-POD objects

So, are std::vectors< uint64_t > considered POD or not? I wish I could tell from reading the above instructions but I cannot. Can someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are, because they do not appear in plain C.